# jQuery ajaxSuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery with `ajaxSuccess`.

I have a preloaded HTML.

My jQuery code is:

```
abc();

function abc() {
$('.clickme').click(function() {
alert('');
// some ajax code and it will give some html //
});
 $('.secondClass').click(function()  {
     //some ajax code///

  });

}
```

The above code all in document ready function.
Now, when I'm using `ajaxSuccess` function:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function( event, request, settings ) { abc(); }
```

Now when I click on the `.clickme` class, it is sending multiple requests to the server.

How to solve this?

Comment: It is because whenever a ajax request is made you are adding a new handler to the targetted elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is because whenever a ajax request is made you are adding a new handler to the targeted elements.

I think you are doing it to handle dynamically added elements, for that purpose instead of using ajax callback use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
jQuery(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.clickme', function () {
        alert('');
        // some ajax code and it will give some html //
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.secondClass', function () {
        //some ajax code///

    });
})
```

In such case there is no need to have the `abc` method.

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/532jd/1/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/532jd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

No Need to write click events inside a method abc(). Just write directly inside document.Ready thats enough to achieve what you are trying to accomplish above

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '.clickme', function() {
         alert('');
         // some ajax code and it will give some html //
     });
     $(document).on('click', '.secondClass', function() {
         //some ajax code///

     });
 });
```

This wont trigger multiple requests.. Hope it helps

Comment: How to make  code for 
    $("div.recent_articles").smoothDivScroll({
                    autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
                });